# JFreeChart - XYBarChart Show Separate Bars for Each Series

Tags: java, jfreechart, bar-chart

I'm creating a XYBarChart using JFreeChart and adding multiple series to it. Currently for a given x-value and different Y-values from the series, all of them are getting stacked on top of each other.

Would be possible to show each series as a different bar for a given x-value?

**Edit**: I'm posting the relevant section of my code that is used to create the chart for your reference.

**Note that** I cannot use *CategoryDataset* because this does not provide zooming capabilities on the Domain Axis. This is an essential requirement for my implementation.

```
XYSeriesCollection intervalXYDataSet  = new XYSeriesCollection();
int countPlotPoints = populateBandData(intervalXYDataSet, optionList); //optionList is a HashMap<Integer,ArrayList<Integer>> where key = seriesKey, and ArrayList<Integer> builds up the value for each series

if (countPlotPoints == 0) {
    print("No options selected.\n");
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "No Plot Points Were Selected!", "Warning", JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
    return;
}

/**
 * Chart Creation Section
 */
JFreeChart chart = ChartFactory.createXYBarChart(tabTitle, "Frequency Bands", false, "rxlev", intervalXYDataSet, PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true, true, false);
XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
plot.getRangeAxis().setStandardTickUnits(NumberAxis.createIntegerTickUnits());
plot.getDomainAxis().setAutoRange(true);

//        
final XYBarRenderer renderer = (XYBarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();
renderer.setDrawBarOutline(false);
renderer.setShadowVisible(false);
renderer.setMargin(0.2);
renderer.setDefaultShadowsVisible(false);

ChartPanel chartpanel = new ChartPanel(chart);
chartpanel.setDefaultDirectoryForSaveAs(new File(lastAnalyzedPath));

JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setTitle(plotTitle);
frame.add(new JScrollPane(chartpanel));
frame.pack();
frame.setVisible(true);

frame.addWindowListener(new java.awt.event.WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public  void windowClosing(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {
        try {
            System.out.println(":: Clearning Memory ::");
            System.out.println("\tFree Memory (Before cleanup): "+Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
            Component component = getComponent(0);
            if(component instanceof ChartPanel){
                JFreeChart chart = ((ChartPanel) component).getChart();
                XYPlot plot = (XYPlot) chart.getPlot();
                plot        = null;
                chart       = null;
                component   = null;
            }
        } finally {
            System.runFinalization();
            System.gc();
            System.out.println("\tFree Memory (Post cleanup): "+Runtime.getRuntime().freeMemory());
        }
    }
});
```

[Here's a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0kEk8.png) of how it's currently appearing
[image]

Comment: Is your code using *XYBarRenderer*, not *StackedXYBarRenderer*?. Can you please post the code that creates the bar chart?.

Comment: @sperumal: just updated my post. is this helpful?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**EDIT** Use `ClusteredXYBarRenderer` instead of `XYBarRenderer`. This draws adjacent bars (instead of StackedBars) and provides zooming capabilities.

There is no factory method in `ChartFactory` to create `ClusteredXYBarRenderer`.

Use the below method to create the Bar Chart.

```
private static JFreeChart createClusteredChart(String title, String categoryAxisLabel, String valueAxisLabel, IntervalXYDataset dataset) {

  NumberAxis domainAxis = new NumberAxis(categoryAxisLabel);
  domainAxis.setAutoRangeIncludesZero(false);

  ValueAxis valueAxis = new NumberAxis(valueAxisLabel);

  XYBarRenderer renderer = new ClusteredXYBarRenderer();

  XYPlot plot = new XYPlot(dataset, domainAxis, valueAxis, renderer);
  plot.setOrientation(PlotOrientation.VERTICAL);

  JFreeChart chart = new JFreeChart(title, JFreeChart.DEFAULT_TITLE_FONT, plot, true);

  return chart;
}
```

`XYBarRenderer` that you are using is correct. But I think you should use `CategoryDataSet` instead of `XYSeriesCollection`. Try using below dataset instead of `XYSeriesCollection`. This will produce adjacent bars instead of stacked bars.

```
private static CategoryDataset createDataset() {
  String series1 = "First";
  String series2 = "Second";
  String series3 = "Third";

  String category1 = "Category 1";
  String category2 = "Category 2";
  String category3 = "Category 3";
  String category4 = "Category 4";
  String category5 = "Category 5";

  DefaultCategoryDataset dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();

  dataset.addValue(1.0D, series1, category1);
  dataset.addValue(4.0D, series1, category2);
  dataset.addValue(3.0D, series1, category3);
  dataset.addValue(5.0D, series1, category4);
  dataset.addValue(5.0D, series1, category5);

  dataset.addValue(5.0D, series2, category1);
  dataset.addValue(7.0D, series2, category2);
  dataset.addValue(6.0D, series2, category3);
  dataset.addValue(8.0D, series2, category4);
  dataset.addValue(4.0D, series2, category5);

  dataset.addValue(4.0D, series3, category1);
  dataset.addValue(3.0D, series3, category2);
  dataset.addValue(2.0D, series3, category3);
  dataset.addValue(3.0D, series3, category4);
  dataset.addValue(6.0D, series3, category5);

  return dataset;
}
```

Comment: The problem using CategoryDataset is that it does not provide zooming capabilities for the Domain axis. This is a very important requirement for my implementation :(

Comment: That sounds fantastic.  I'll try using this technique for time series bar charts.

Comment: to use CategoryDataset  I  have to change Plot implementation could you please tell me how can I change it ?

Comment: Use a DefaultTableXYDataset with multiple XYSeries added to it as dataset parameter for the createClusteredChart method instead of the CategoryDataset which won't work.